# How can I calculate the mean and standard deviation given three percentiles using Matlab?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, computational-statistics, quantiles

I have the percentiles of 3 values. The percentiles are 5th, 50th and 95th. The values respectively are 340, 365 and 385. How can I find the median and the standard deviation given that data follow a normal distribution?

Comment: The 50th percentile *is* the median!

Answer (score 1):

The 50th percentile is the median.
I used `qnorm(0.05)` in R to estimate the number of standard deviations the 5th percentile is from the mean, given a normal distribution. It's 1.644854.
Good luck!

Comment: can you explain it please with more detail .I am not good at maths at all

Comment: R is software that can be used (among others) statistical analyses. [link](http://r-project.org)  

You could have looked that 1.64 up in a table as well, but I had an R session open anyway :-)

_saw your edit_
If 340 is 1.64 sd away from the mean (in the normal distribution very similar to the median), that means: `sd = (365 - 340) / 1.644854 = 15.19892`.

Comment: yes but you didnt use the 95th percentile .I cant understand your logic :( :(

Comment: Because a normal distribution is symmetrical, the 95th and the 5th percentile should be equally far away from the mean. In your example that's not the case (I'm sorry I missed that). If you were to calculate it from the 95th to the 50th percentile, you would get a slightly different number.
Or you could use that the difference of the 95th and 5th percentile is 2*1.644 sd.

Comment: so in this case as you calculated ,the sd =15.19 right?

Comment: I'm glad I could help :-) Could you mark this answer as the correct one if you're satisfied?